# Server JVM not to retain memory

Tags: java, memory-management

One of the differences between server and client JVM is that server JVM will try to use and retain all available memory (up to configured or default Xmx), but client JVM is 'merciful' to user machine and will not retain unused memory (source?).
On machine with large amount of memory and several CPUs 'server' JVM will be chousen by default, resulting in quite big default Xmx and 'server memory retantion policy'.
This will cause small java application slowly grabbing 4G of memory when in practice it needs only 100M.
How could I change 'server JVM memory retantion policy' to act like 'client' JVM, but not downgrade other 'server JVM performance improvements'?

Comment: Why not just set an explicit Xmx value?

Comment: Because you need to 'guess' how much would be enough for your app and you need to set more than that. Thus, several times you'll get OOME then you'll set more that application really need and it will  slowly use all of it. With this option you can never be 'precise'.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming HotSpot JVM, Java 9. You can set a hard limit for heap size with `-Xmx`, or instruct the JVM to return memory to the OS if a sufficient ratio of the heap is unused with `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` (in which case you should also set `-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio`).

The section [Performance Tuning Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR-GUID-EE6BD9FA-EF6D-4C3E-AC5C-30B8762CDC1B) in the Java 9 docs recommends

```
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5
```

for keeping the heap small.